# Replace a part of a url with php

Tags: php, regex, url, youtube

Hey there!
I have a simple question that I am struggling with, hope you guys can have a look.
I have a input field where users would put in YouTube links and your typical single page works fine, for example:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=c3sBBRxDAqk
```

this `watch?v=11characters` works fine

but if the users inputs anything other than the above example, such as:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=tC0E1id4raw&feature=topvideos
//or
youtube.com/watch?v=smETLCCPTVo&feature=aso
```

is there a way to take the 2 above urls and remove any characters after the w`atch?v=11characters`?

so in essence, turn this

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=tC0E1id4raw&feature=topvideos"
```

into

```
youtube.com/watch?v=tC0E1id4raw removing & and onwards
```

I had to remove the http bit due to spam prevention

is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php exist for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=tC0E1id4raw&feature=topvideos";

$newurl = explode("&", $url);
```

Everything before the "&" will be in $newurl[0], and everything after it will be in $newurl[1].

Comment: this works best in my given situation, i guess i forgot about explode lol, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=tC0E1id4raw&feature=topvideos";

list($keep, $chuck) = explode('&', $url);

echo $keep;
```

Comment: I was writing an answer that used strpos, but I like your answer more. Upvote!

Comment: or you could use $keep = current(explode('&', $url));

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$params = array();
parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
```

If you have PECL pecl_http installed:

```
$url = http_build_url($url, 
                      array('query' => 'v='. $params['v']), 
                      HTTP_URL_REPLACE | HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT);
```

Or without pecl_http:

```
$url = $parts['scheme'] . $parts['host'] .  $parts['path'] .  '?v=' . $params['v'];
```

This is more robust against changes of the order of the query parameters.

Reference: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), [`http_build_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

Comment: I did test this out and it works but I am a total noob in php and I had trouble following the code a bit, I need to study more! thanks =D